# Move label from one position to another in unity when the game is running

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, label, 2d

I'm making a simple 2D game in Unity. 
I have two labels, one that shows current score and another highscore. Can I move these label form one position to another when the game is running? I want a "jump-in" effect. Hope you guys can help.

```
    public void ShowEndScore(Font font, float coins, int highscore)
    {
        GUIStyle style = new GUIStyle();
        style.fontSize = 150;
        style.fontStyle = FontStyle.Bold;
        style.normal.textColor = Color.yellow;
        style.alignment = TextAnchor.UpperCenter;
        style.font = font;


        GUI.Label (new Rect (Screen.width / 2 - 50, Screen.height / 2 - 50,     100, 50), "Your score: "+ coins, style);
        GUI.Label (new Rect (Screen.width / 2 - 50, Screen.height / 2, 100, 50), "Highscore: "+ highscore, style);
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried to complete this task, that didn't work? From your code all we can gather is that you created two labels.

Comment: @EBrown I have not tried yet because I do not have one clue how to - sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Unity are you using?

I would recommend to use the 4.6 UI system (so use unity 4.6 or above) and just change the position of the text via a script or even animate the "jump-in".

You can find a nice tutorial about the new UI and animation with it etc here:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/78675/unity-new-gui-part-1

I hope that helps :)

Comment: The reason why i don't use UI system is that it don't have "Label" but only "Text" - i think. And for some reason i can't increase size of "Text" to my need, which i can with "Label"

Comment: if you add a text in your editor, press "t" to see the text rectangle and then you can make it as big as you want it to be. ;)

Comment: np :) Good luck with your game